# How to get value-data of a div using POST?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a div as followed:

```
<div id="progress_status" class="slider slider-blue"  data-min="0" data-max="365" data-value="1"></div>
```

I would like to get the div value and process it by the post method. How do I do this using JavaScript?

**Edit:** I need to retrieve the value and insert it in the database: basically we work with the name attribute:

```
$row['delai']=$post['delai']
```

Comment: i see only HTML and you want a javascirpt solution. where does the PHP come in?

Comment: `document.getElementById('progress_status').getAttribute('data-value')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i solve the problem by adding a hidden element:

```
<input type="hidden" name="delaiDePrise" id="delai">
```

and then call a function on submitting the form:

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$("form").submit(function(){

    var val2 = $('#progress_status span').text();

    document.getElementById('delai').value = val2;
});});
```